# AccessDeniedException in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: java, android, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to amazon Dynamo DB. I am getting the access denied Exception.
Please help me out from this.

Error:

> User: arn:aws:sts::xx:assumed-role/Cognito_SampleUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource: arn:xxx

Answer (score 3):

Firstly make sure that your assumed role have permission to access DynamoDB.

If you run app from your laptop and not on EC2/Beanstalk, make sure that you set STS credentials (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-cli.html).

For receiving credentials from assumed role you can use the following:

```
public Credentials getCredentialsFromAssumedRole() {
        AWSSecurityTokenService awsSecurityTokenService = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
                .withRoleArn("arn:aws:iam::XX:role/assume-role-DynamoDB-ReadOnly")
                .withDurationSeconds(3600)
                .withRoleSessionName("assumed-role-session");

        AssumeRoleResult assumeResult = awsSecurityTokenService.assumeRole(assumeRequest);
        Credentials credentials = assumeResult.getCredentials();
        return credentials;
    }
```

After that you can create DynamoDBMapper instanse:

```
AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(amazonAWSCredentials);
        amazonDynamoDB.setEndpoint(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint);
        amazonDynamoDB.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.valueOf(amazonAWSRegion)));
        return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);
```

and with DynamoDBMapper you could do CRUD operations like:

```
dynamoDBMapper.save(entity);
dynamoDBMapper.load(Entity.class, entityId);
```

@karthik, Is it similar that you did before? Please post your code to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: I am using an example given in the following URL. i am using this application "DynamoDBMapper_UserPreference_Cognito"..  In that application i changes my credentials and region only..

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples..

Comment: got same problem using same examples - my CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider sets the region to EU_WEST_1 and i have a table in eu-west-1 but keeps giving me error saying i am not authorized to access the table in us-east-1 - but this table does not exist! - it is not seeing my table in the eu-west-1 region! crazy!!!!